# How do you use the Microsoft Dynamic Dictionary with the translator API

Tags: python-3.x, microsoft-translator

How do you use the [Dynamic Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/dynamic-dictionary) feature of the Microsoft Translator Text API with json as input?  The linked documentation is very unclear.

I am following this [example](https://github.com/MicrosoftTranslator/Text-Translation-API-V3-Python/blob/master/Translate.py) from Microsoft's gitHub page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/reference/v3-0-translate?tabs=curl#translate-with-dynamic-dictionary) with the python [examples](https://github.com/MicrosoftTranslator/Text-Translation-API-V3-Python/blob/master/Translate.py) with the following input

```
text = "Instant dictionary: word <mstrans:dictionary translation=\"wordomatic\">word or phrase</mstrans:dictionary> is a dictionary entry."
```

gives the following output:

```
[
    {
        "translations": [
            {
                "text": "Instant Dictionary Word wordomatic ist ein Wörterbucheintrag.",
                "to": "de"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

So that answers *this* question.

However, somehow everything before the tagged word is not translated.

Also, translating `text = "Instant dictionary: word"` returns:
`{"translations": [{"text": "Instant Dictionary: Word","to": "de"}]}`

Whereas translating `text = "Instant dictionary word"` returns:
`{"translations": [{"text": "Instant Wörterbuchwort","to": "de"}]}`

This leads to the question: How do these words and characters change what the API returns?